# Custom Control in Xamarin.Forms from scratch

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to write a custom control which will look like [this](https://github.com/nicklockwood/CountryPicker) one using Xamarin.Forms. I know that when we want to modify the existing control from Xamarin.Forms we are using [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/), but this control is something more than `Entry` and the solution is not obvious to me.

My question is how do I start working on this task? What control should I extend if I would like to use custom renderer? Is there some other more effective way to achieve this?

Comment: More info about how I did is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219874/customrenderer-for-uipickerview

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the linked control is extending a `UIPickerView`.

You have two options

1. Create the [binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/) for https://github.com/nicklockwood/CountryPicker
2. Create your own Xamarin.Forms control, which is basically a custom renderer. You can refer the [Forms source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) to create the controls for it.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a pure Xamarin.Forms view class and renderers (inherited from `ViewRenderer`) for each platform.

Please have a look at XLabs projects - it should be a good point to start:

- Cross-platfrom view: [`Separator.cs`](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/e23832282b312cc6da6495da82f29081635fe1bb/source/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/Separator.cs).
- Android renderer: [`SeparatorRenderer.cs`](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/e23832282b312cc6da6495da82f29081635fe1bb/source/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Droid/Controls/Separator/SeparatorRenderer.cs).

Comment: Alternatively, the Xamarin.Forms source is [available to view on Github](http://github.com/xamarin/xamarin.forms), and provides a similar jumping point for seeing how the Picker is rendered on each platform.