# CustomRenderer for UIPickerView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

It is possible to make a `UIPickerView` always visible in place where it is defined in XAML?

Standard behavior of this controls shows the binded list only when we clicked `Title` property, then from the bottom of the screen (iOS) or in the popup(Android) is showing a widget which contains a list as a content.

I would like to make this visible from start and in the place where it is defined (not in the widget). There is no something like `Position` in `picker` object.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        List<string> names = new List<string>()
        {
            "test",
            "test 2"
        };

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var picker = (UIPickerView)this.Control.InputView;
            picker.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem and made a sample project repository available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/CustomPicker).

Sample code:

```
<local:CustomObjectPicker
            ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectList}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            IsTransparent="true"
            TextColor="Blue"
            />
```

It is based on `CustomRenderer` and works only on iOS since `UIPickerView` is a native iOS control.